# How to take data from object from BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, object, blockingqueue

I have class for an object with all the fields and getters. Now, one thread is putting some data into it, in my case

```
object = new MyObject(int, int, char, int) 
queue.put(object);
```

and then puts it into BlockingQueue, then the second thread is taking this object

```
MyObject toSolve = queue.take();
```

My question is how to take the data from object to make operations using its ints.

Comment: you said you had getters.... use the getters?

Comment: the above code does not compile - there is no constructor for `(int, int, char, int)`

Comment: the above comment is just single lines of code... I thought it was obvious I had a class Object with a constructor...

Comment: that ... doesnt make any sense whatsoever

Comment: because your sentence doesnt make sense. `Object` is a JVM/JRE/JDK class, you cant create your own in a global / public scope and SO-comments cant include much more than a few sentences, additionally : it would'nt make sense to write more in this very case. Are you confused, perhaps?

Comment: Ahhh, true, my bad... I had in mind something different, I meant Object==MyObject class from post. I should use here non-confusing names. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you don't actually mean you're using `Object`? If yes, then I'm guessing your problem is that you put a `YourClass` on the queue, but get an `java.lang.Object` out.

If you look at [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) you'll see it is genericized, so writing something like (notice the `<>`'s)

```
BlockingQueue bq = new BlockingQueue<YourClass>();
bq.put( new YourClass( 1 , 2 , 'a' , 42 ) );
```

then

```
YourClass yq = bq.take();
```

will work like a charm, both in terms of compilation and function, and you can use the getters on `yq` to obtain your `int`'s and `char`.

Use generics, that's what they're there for.

Cheers,